# Stepwise column sum in data frame based on another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, vectorization

I have a data frame like this:

| Team | GF |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 6 |

Looking for output like this (just an additional column):

| Team | x | avg(X) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 2.5 |
| B | 1 | 5 |
| B | 6 | 3 |

avg(x) is the average of all previous instances of x where Team is the same. I have the following R code which gets the overall average, however I'm looking for the "step-wise" average.

```
    new_df <- df %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(avg_x = mean(x))
```

Is there a way to vectorize this while only evaluating the previous rows on each  "iteration"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `cummean()` function from `dplyr`, combined with `lag()`:

```
df %>% group_by(Team) %>% mutate(avg_x = replace_na(lag(cummean(x)), 0))
```

Producing the following:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   Team [2]
  Team      x avg_x
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         3   0
2 B         5   0
3 A         2   3
4 A         3   2.5
5 B         1   5
6 B         6   3
```

As required.

#### Edit 1:

As [@Ritchie Sacramento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835261/ritchie-sacramento) pointed out, the following is cleaner and clearer:

```
df %>% group_by(Team) %>% mutate(avg_x = lag(cummean(x), default = 0))
```